# Formatting of lombok generated code

Tags: java, checkstyle, lombok

My Java constants class contains the following line:

```
public static final List<String> VALID_SUBMISSION_CONTEXT_TYPE_STRINGS = Stream.of(SubmissionContextType.values())
                                                                                    .map(Enum::name)
                                                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My checkstyle configuration has a line length limit of 120 characters, and the above line is within this limit.

I also use lombok @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) on this constants class. The generated lombok code is:

```
public static final List<String> VALID_SUBMISSION_CONTEXT_TYPE_STRINGS = Stream.of(SubmissionContextType.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This exceeds 120 characters on the line and causes checkstyle to fail.

Is there a way to tell lombok to restrict the length of lines in the generated code, or to preserve the whitespaces from the source code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023185/how-to-disable-a-particular-checkstyle-rule-for-a-particular-line-of-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto generated code should be skipped by Checkstyle. See [Automatically generated code fails CheckStyle standards (jHipster)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298601/automatically-generated-code-fails-checkstyle-standards-jhipster/45306678#45306678) for a complete answer.

Comment: I was hoping against hope, to get something working on the generated code :).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortonetly propably it isn't possible.

I think in that case you should run checkstyle scan before lombok code is generated.